# Sql query is failing in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, table-alias

I run below query to fetch data from a `Oracle DB` -

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T2.Col1 AS Tab2_Col1 
    FROM Tab1 AS T1  
        INNER JOIN Tab2 AS T2         
        ON Tab1.Col3 = Tab2.Col4
```

With that, I am getting below error -

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 32
```

Can someone help me to understand why my query is failing?

Thanks for your time

Comment: You have a double quote in there somewhere.

Comment: In the above query? I dont think I have put double quote anywhere in the query. I see some marking though under `AS T1` in above query. Any idea, why?

Comment: Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases, remove it. e.g. `from tab1 t1`